# Improving connection speed between postgresql and php

Tags: php, performance, apache, networking, pgbouncer

I have a setup for connecting to a postgresql database the works like this:

1. Apache
2. PHP pg_connect
3. prepared_statement
4. ip address to server
5. pg_bouncer
6. unix socket
7. return queried data

When I return the query without PHP it takes 900 milliseconds to execute, or .9 seconds. But the page load with the query takes 4 seconds to load, so that is around 3 seconds in connection. I'm using Rackspace as my hosting so its not the connection speed. How can I improve the performance of PHP connecting to to the database database server?

Comment: are both your database and php server hosted by Rackspace ?

Comment: could it be some static elements like js/css/images on your page that are taking more time to load ? Is your code referring to some external elements on a different domain that could be slowing things down ?

Comment: Yes they are, and I use the private ip to connect

Comment: If your query is running fast without PHP so I doubt its the database that is the issue. Did you profile your page using network tab in tools like firebug or chrome/ie developer ?

Comment: No, I'm not measuring js/css/images, just how long it takes to output the data from the database.

Comment: Yes, I use Chrome and that hows I got the 4 seconds to load the index

Comment: so your php page just displays database results ?

Comment: Yes, only the db results. Just a print_r($results);

Comment: then it could be your database. Even though it takes only 900 ms to execute, its possible that its taking more time to fetch results from the database.

Comment: Why do you think that 3 seconds is connection speed to the PostgreSQL database?  Never guess on these things.  Run tests, profiling, etc.  You need to find out how long it is actually taking to print_r() vs startup the connection vs fetch the data.  Then we can talk.

Comment: Also if your setup is this complex, you need to profile *every link* before determining where the problem is.

Comment: Please show the benchmark. You need to encapsulate the actual php query execution to know the time it took, not the time it took to reach your screen.